# Turing machine accepting words of "1" arrange-able into square

Tags: automata, finite-automata, computation-theory, turing-machines

I'm trying to figure out following assignment and I could use your help, because I'm stuck. I'm not aiming for direct answer (but I don't mind if someone is capable of designing the whole machine). I'm more interested in **approving/disproving** my thoughts and pointing in the right directions.

**Task:**

Construct a Turing machine accepting words in format `1^k, where k=n^2  n is integer`.
Basically it accepts those words, where you can arrange ones into square.
For example first three acceptable words will be:

```
1Δ; 1111Δ; 111111111Δ;
```

Which are arrange-able into squares like this:

```
1

11
11

111
111
111
```

**My thoughts:**

If I get "1" only once, it should be accepted.

`Tape: 1Δ; k=1, n=1 and k=n^2`

So I m assuming after one "1" I'm in the "STOP" state (lets call it state *A*) if there is no other char on the tape.

The next acceptable word is the next square, which we I can write in the formula like this:

```
(n+1)^2  That equals: n^2 + 2*n + 1
```

Difference between two consecutive squares is `(2*n + 1)`

So If my assumption is correct, If I'm in state *A* I need to somehow check if I get `(2*n + 1)` times "1" on tape and if that takes me back to state *A*, it will be correctly accepted. Anything else should be declined.

The problem I'm facing is, that I don't know, how to count `(2*n + 1)` times "1" on tape.

Also I should find solution using only one tape. The hint is that it should end in the form
`111#111111111Δ`, where the left side sum of ones equals "*k*" and right side equals "*n*". Sadly, this hint didn't help me at all. I'd say it made things worse for me.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want a single-tape machine that you know will work and you don't care about efficiency, consider the following:

1. copy the input to the end of the tape, separated from the original input by a separator
2. write a number k (from 1 on up) in unary on the end of the tape, separated from the copy by a second separator
3. divide the copy by the counter k by iteratively subtracting k from the copy and marking one of the k crossed-off symbols of the copy with a special symbol
4. provided that the division in step 3 left 0 remainder, divide again in the same way but only considering the specially marked symbols
5. provided the division in step 4 left 0 remainder, see if the quotient was 1. if so, you found input = k^2 and can halt-accept. otherwise, you can halt-reject when k > input.

Example on input 1111:

```
   1111
-> 1111A1111       // copy input
-> 1111A1111B1     // add counter
-> 1111A3333B1     // divide by 1 by bouncing back and forth, marking every 1th
-> 1111A5555B1     // repeat
-> 1111A1111B11    // don't have one 5, so copy input and increment counter
-> 1111A3232B11    // divide by 2 by bouncing back and forth, marking every 2nd
-> 1111A5242B11    // divide by 2 again considering only 3s from last step
-> accept          // halt-accept since one 5 remaining means input = k^2
```

Your way works too. You can keep track of the current n (or k) and iteratively cross off 2n + 1 of the 1s in your copy at each stage. Something like:

```
   1111
-> 1111A1111    // copy input
-> 1111A1111B   // begin counter at 0
-> 1111A2111B   // cross off 1 in the copy
-> 1111A2111B1  // increment counter
-> 1111A2222B1  // cross off 3 in the copy
-> accept       // all symbols crossed off
```

If what's getting you is the actual mechanics of "bouncing back and forth" to cross off, subtract, divide, etc., the idea is that you change the symbol you're crossing off to one you recognize as meaning it has been marked for that purpose; change state so you know what you need to go mark off next; go mark that off; then, return to the first unmarked symbol (if any) where you started.